# How can I get the percentage of a cell based on a different cell value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, percentage

How to calculate a cell with % based on another cell's value?

For example: Let's say A2 = 5000, I want C2 to calculate 1% of A2 if B2 = yes

Will the following work?

```
SUMIFS(B2,"TRUE",C2*1%)
```

Comment: Please add sample data from your sheet to help others to answer

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1loFDFZcbS11mgHRTDlTg97rcWdnffpkCIINapdUmHXY/edit?usp=sharing
see F2

Answer (score 1):

In C2, Try something like

```
=sumproduct(B2="yes", A2*0.01)
```

or

```
=if(B2="yes", A2*0.01,)
```

and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following as a formula for `C2`:

```
=IF(B2="yes", A2*0.01, 0)
```

Comment: @Zalmen please add sample data from your sheet for us to be able to test

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1loFDFZcbS11mgHRTDlTg97rcWdnffpkCIINapdUmHXY/edit?usp=sharing
see F2